# How can I write a WebDAV server with Delphi?

Tags: c#, java, delphi, webdav

There are some WebDAV clients available for Delphi (for example included in Indy 10). Is there also a simple WebDAV server solution written with Delphi?

If there is none yet, maybe you know an implementation in a different language (C#, Java) which you can recommend as a starting point for a WebDAV server implementation? (It does not have to be a full-featured solution, a rather simple skeleton could be even more helpful.)

Comment: if you want to program it by yourself, you might want to start reading the specs first: http://www.webdav.org/specs/

Comment: Did You found or made any appropriate library?

Comment: Another starting point could be this Perl implementation of a WebDAV server: https://github.com/DanRohde/webdavcgi/tree/master/lib/perl

Answer (score 1):

Start your search on Google for [Delphi WebDAV](http://www.google.nl/search?q=webdav+Delphi) or [Delphi WebDAV Component](http://www.google.nl/search?q=webdav+Delphi+component)
That will give you some starting points: there indeed are components that can help you out.

--jeroen

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, WebDav extends HTTP functionality. You should try extending some HTTP server code. I believe [synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/) would be good point to start, as the code is very clear (also I personally don't like Indy ;) )

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/), it has a WebDAV interface available (Java solution).

Answer (score -1):

May be Go implementation can be taken as a start point.

Related links:

- https://github.com/golang/net/tree/master/webdav
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=webdav
- [Webdav Server in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278501/webdav-server-in-go)

Comment: Question have part "If there is none yet, maybe you know an implementation in a different language (C#, Java) which you can recommend as a starting point for a WebDAV server implementation?" and this is an answer for this part.